# Cannot connect GAE app to Cloud SQL in remote regions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, region

My Google App Engine application is hosted in the USA region. There is no option to select any other region during set-up.

My Google Cloud SQL server instance is in the Europe region. This was a choice I made during set-up. I want my database to be hosted in Europe because the stored data will be Europe specific.

I cannot connect my GAE app to my Google SQL server because they are in different regions.

I deduce this from the received exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

and the warning I receive from the Developer console when I try to authorise the app for the SQL server:
"Authorized GAE applications must be in the same region as the database instance"

Does anyone know how I can 'move' my GAE application to the European servers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @RowlandShaw It's only off topic if you aren't familiar with creating applications.  Appengine questions seemingly get routinely voted by MSFT tech users as being off-topic but that seems more a statement of familiarity as opposed to meeting any definition of programming.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have billing enabled.

Then, you need to set it up when you create the app.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/location

If you have a [Premier Account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/), you can choose where the application runs when you create it in the Console.

For all other applications, you must fill out the [European Offering request form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDllb3FHLS1IdXVIcjVKR3FScklka1E6MQ).